# Magento 2.0.7 "Urlkey for the store already exists" error while importing products

Tags: magento2, import, products

I am trying to import simple products, But it fails due to some validation error.
The error message i get is "Additional data: URL key for specified store already exists.".

I have checked the URL keys generated from the product names are all unique. but still i am having this annoying issue.

I am importing >10000 products.

Answer (score 0):

The "URL key for specified store already exists" can be misleading I found and doesn't always refer to products. We were also using the import to create categories as well and found that if you have a same category name in multiple sublevels it would also create that error but you'd have no idea where the error was coming from. If you are creating categories at the same time as part of the import maybe scroll through the list and see what the last category created is and compare that with import.